# Using Fetch to get an API response, using JSON.stringify(), and then...?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, mapbox

I have searched this nine ways from Sunday, but there's something I'm missing here, and I don't know what it is.

I'm using fetch to grab some data from Mapbox:

```
var response = fetch(myURL)

.then(response => response.json())
.then (data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
```

When I run this and look at the console, I can see that I have indeed grabbed the data, because it gets logged. (I'm putting what got logged at the end because it's a lot.)

The problem is I don't know how to get the information into a format where I can work with it. All I want is the lat/long, but I can't work out how to get it. I tried pushing the stringified data into an array, I tried writing an function that assigned the stringified data to a variable, and I'm not getting it.

It's probably something really obvious that I'm missing. If you could unblind me I'd sure appreciate it.

Here's what shows up in the console log.

"type":"FeatureCollection","query":["1600","pennsylvania","avenue","washington","dc"],"features":[{"id":"address.1048737153875776","type":"Feature","place_type":["address"],"relevance":0.90963,"properties":{"accuracy":"rooftop"},"text":"Pennsylvania Avenue Southeast","place_name":"1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Southeast, Washington, District of Columbia 20003, United States","matching_place_name":"1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Southeast, Washington, DC 20003, United States","center":[-76.982015,38.879235],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-76.982015,38.879235]},"address":"1600","context":[{"id":"neighborhood.2918372884011750","text":"Capitol Hill"},{"id":"postcode.12587193810898840","text":"20003"},{"id":"place.2915387490246050","wikidata":"Q61","text":"Washington"},{"id":"region.14064402149979320","short_code":"US-DC","wikidata":"Q3551781","text":"District of Columbia"},{"id":"country.14135384517372290","wikidata":"Q30","short_code":"us","text":"United States"}]}],"attribution":"NOTICE: © 2022 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare."}

Comment: Why are stringifying it? Just work with the parsed JSON.

Comment: Because that's the only way I could see any data in the console log? When I tried using JSON.parse nothing ended up in the console.

Comment: You don't have to parse the data again. `.json()` parses the JSON from the server. All you would need to do is `.then(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: But what happens after that? How do you work with the data? That's where I'm stuck. What good is it doing logged to the console?

Comment: See my answer below.   You could do an ajax call to post and save to database or generate some html to display in a table/convert to a csv file or something .  What do you actually want to do with the data?

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an object. And assuming you want the `lat/lng` information in the `coordinates` array you can navigate it like this.

```js
const data={type:"FeatureCollection",query:["1600","pennsylvania","avenue","washington","dc"],features:[{id:"address.1048737153875776",type:"Feature",place_type:["address"],relevance:.90963,properties:{accuracy:"rooftop"},text:"Pennsylvania Avenue Southeast",place_name:"1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Southeast, Washington, District of Columbia 20003, United States",matching_place_name:"1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Southeast, Washington, DC 20003, United States",center:[-76.982015,38.879235],geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates:[-76.982015,38.879235]},address:"1600",context:[{id:"neighborhood.2918372884011750",text:"Capitol Hill"},{id:"postcode.12587193810898840",text:"20003"},{id:"place.2915387490246050",wikidata:"Q61",text:"Washington"},{id:"region.14064402149979320",short_code:"US-DC",wikidata:"Q3551781",text:"District of Columbia"},{id:"country.14135384517372290",wikidata:"Q30",short_code:"us",text:"United States"}]}]};

// Access the first element of the `features` array and
// find the `geometry` property. Destructure the `coordinates`
// property (also and array) from it.
const { coordinates } = data.features[0].geometry;

// And then destructure the `lat/lng` values from
// that array
const [lat, lng] = coordinates;

console.log(lat, lng);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score -1):

The response.json() is a JavaScript object.  So something like this should work for you.   I'm just logging to the console here, but you could save the data to a database via an ajax call or dynamically create a html table to view the details.

```
var response = fetch(myURL)
    .then(response => {
        responseObject = response.json();
        let features = responseObject.features;        
        for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++)
        {
            let coords = responseObject.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
            console.log(`${features.id} Lat = ${coords[0]} Long = ${coords[1]}`);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That won't work. You can't completely ignore arrays in a data structure.

Comment: I was just suggesting the solution is to get the data you need from the JavaScript object.  This was just a quick example to point you in the right direction.   I'm not familiar with the data structure.
It the features property an array?   
What data do you need  to get, the coordinates of each property?

Comment: If you think a question is unclear, comment on it and (when you have a little more reputation) vote to close it. Don't give answers that are just going to throw exceptions because they don't match the data structure that appears in the question. Also don't confuse people commenting on your answer with the person who asked the original question.

Comment: Quentin sorry about confusing you with the person who asked the question.   No offence intended.